# JSP вызов java метода и получение ответа без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: servlet, jsp, java

Всем привет,

на JSP странице имеется кнопка:
`<input type="button" value="Сохранить файл" onclick="" />` по нажатию на которую произойдет вызов java метода. Страницу перезагружать нельзя. Для теста, например вызвать метод класса:

```
public class FileLoader {

    private String files;

    public void loadFiles() {
        System.out.println("OK");                   
    }
```

Тоесть, если 5 раз нажать кнопку, в консоль выведится 5 раз "ОК".
Второй день бьюсь, ничего не получается. Нужны ваши настравления, как правильно делать такие вызовы, желательно с примерами. Большое спасибо

Comment: при нажатии на любые элементы типа <input> у тебя браузер будет делать отдельные запросы к серверу с перезагрузкой страницы. при отдаче JSP страницы браузеру, у тебя произведётся ряд вызовов в java  код и страница будет сгенерирована. но вызов из браузера, никак напрямую не связан напрямую с вызовом сервера. для асинхронного вызова методов сервлета, курить маны про AJAX. если непонятно, пингуй.

Answer (score 2):

Как я помню, то без перезагрузки необойтись, если не использовать ajax. Если его юзать можно, то копайте в єтом направлении.

Comment: Хотя, вам же не отображать єти 5 "Ок" на jsp в браузере. То должно работать если:
Сделать сперва форму отправки <form action="имя_сервлета_обработки" method="POST">
Внутри написать єто: 
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" /><br/>
И закріть форму:
</form>
Єто то что требуеться от jsp страниці, дальше ваше творчетво в сервлете :-)

Comment: Спасибо попробую :) Просто задача такая, что нужен функционал, как в декстопном приложении. Я конечно понимаю, что для того что бы выполнить запрос и получить результат, нужно вначале отправить данные на сервер, а затем получить от него ответ, поэтому и нужны были наставления в какую сторону двигаться.

Comment: Тогда Ajax изучать